# How to pattern match of a API while exposing to Swagger2 in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, pattern-matching, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Below is the controller for which I need to write swagger2 API documents:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc/def/pqr")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping(path = "", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public <T> PagedResources<SomeResource> get(Pageable pageable,
            Assembler assembler) {
        Page<Something> somethings = service.get(pageable);
        return pagedAssembler.toResource(somethings, assembler);
    }
}
```

Below is the code for through which I am trying to write swagger to API documentations:

```
@Bean
public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/abc/def/pqr/"))
            .build()
}
```

But even after writing it, this API is not exposing to swagger2. Wherever, I can understand the problem I thing that there is some problem in **PathSelectors.ant("/abc/def/pqr/")** . So, please someone can help me then it's better for me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()                 .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your.base.package"))
                .paths(regex("/product.*"))
                .build();
    }
}
```